# What happens if I use DateTime in WHERE clause to filter rows against a field that is DateTimeOffset?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, datetimeoffset

What happens if I use DateTime in my WHERE clause to filter rows against a field that is DateTimeOffset?

Does SQL server converts the DateTime field to DateTimeOffset with offset ZERO or...?

For Example:

```
DECLARE @myTime As DateTime = GetDAte()

SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE @myTime > dbo.foo.TimeStampOffset -- TimeStampOffset  is a DateTimeOffset field in foo table
```

Comment: Check [`SQL Datetime / datetimeoffset(2) comparison & implicit cast wierdness`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71150/sql-datetime-datetimeoffset2-comparison-implicit-cast-wierdness) question on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you comparing `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` to `DATETIMEOFFSET` values, an implicit conversions occures.

**DATETIMEOFFSET -> DATETIME2**

> The `date` and `time` are copied to the `DATETIME2` value, and the `time zone` is truncated. When the precision of the `DATETIME2(n)` value is greater than the precision of the `DATETIMEOFFSET (n)` value, the fractional seconds are truncated to fit. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)

**DATETIMEOFFSET -> DATETIME**

> The date and time values are copied, and the time zone is truncated. When the fractional precision of the datetimeoffset(n) value is greater than three digits, the value is truncated. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)

**DATETIMEOFFSET -> DATETIME or DATETIME2**

When a `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` value is converted to `DATETIMEOFFSET`, the original value is treated as a `UTC` value and the offset will be `+00:00`. (The `DATETIME` and `DATETIME2` types do not store the offset of the timezone).

**What happens?**

If your server's timezone is not +00:00, then the comparsion could result false positives and negatives -> the result will not be the desired one.

If you want to compare to the current time, change the declaration of `@myTime` to `DECLARE @myTime As DateTimeOffset = SysDateTimeOffset()`